# Dynamically buiding an XPath query string

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, user-defined-functions

I have a chained XSLT 2.0 transformation scenario (using saxon), like this: 
 - I1.xml is input for T1.xslt, stylesheet which will build T2.xslt 
 - I2.xml is input for T2.xslt, stylesheet which will output O1.xml

I would like to have an xsl:function (so that it will be available in XPath expressions), let's call it my:f( dataNode, queryString ), which will query dataNode using the supplied query, similar with below:

```
<xsl:function name="my:f">
       <xsl:param name="dataNode" as="item()*"/>
       <xsl:param name="query" as="xsd:string"/>
             <xsl:sequence select="$dataNode/$query"/>
</xsl:function>
```

my:f() is stored in a separate file and included only by T2. 
my:f() is isolated in a file because depending on configuration, it might call an extension function for performing the query.
my:f() call is, of course, "build" in T1 ( where the XPath queryString is dynamically concatenated ), but it is actually called only in T2.

The only problem that I seem to have .. is how to actually pass the dynamically build queryString from T1 to T2 and then to my:f() as a simple string (as the actual query will be performed by my:f()).

Does anyone have any ideas (and ideally some code) about how to approach this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to construct and evaluate XPath expressions at run-time then you need to use an extension function like http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/evaluate.xml: `<xsl:sequence select="saxon:evaluate(concat('$p1/', $query), $dataNode)"/>`

Comment: Or you could write it as <xsl:sequence select="$dataNode/saxon:evaluate($query)"/>

Comment: Note that this assumes $query is an XPath expression - it doesn't work for XQuery

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Sir! One more thing; is evaluate() available in Saxon 9.3 HE or only PE/EE?

Comment: As far as I know extension functions like saxon:evaluate are not available in the Home Editions of Saxon 9.2 and 9.3. They are however available in 9.1 Basic.